# Paasing value to the routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I checked a lot questions in Stack overflow but i didn't find the answer so posting here.

I have a button like this in my view

```
 <a class = "btn btn-primary btn-flat" 
href = "{{ route('WaterTanks.create') }}"> Create New Tank</a>
```

And my web route like this

```
Route::resource('WaterTanks', 'WaterTankController');
```

And my controller method like this

```
public function create() {
        return view('WaterTanks.create');
    }
```

what I want is to pass variable in that route may be like this

```
<a class = "btn btn-primary btn-flat"  
href = "{{ route('WaterTanks.create')->with('type','$type') }}"> 
Create New Tank</a>
```

And get that variable in my controller method like this

```
public function create($type) {
        return view('WaterTanks.create')->with('type',$type);
    }
```

But that's not happening Showing this error

```
Call to a member function with() on string
```

So how can I do that

Comment: all you have to do is {{ route('WaterTanks.create', '$type') }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send parameters like this

```
{{ route('WaterTanks.create', ['type' => $type]) }}
```

But using `Route::resource()` does not take parameter in the `create()`. So you have to manually define that route

```
Route::get('WaterTanks/create/{type}', 'WaterTankController@create')->name('WaterTanks.create');
```